# SQLite query not executing properly in a WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I'm working on a WPF application and using SQLite database. I can do every CRUD operation with Entity Framework, but in some specific cases I have to use raw SQL queries, and sometimes it's not returning what I need.

Here is a sample code:

```
using (var db = new DbContext(AppIO.DatabaseFilePath)) {
    var key = 12;
    string sql = $"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeField={key}";
    var result = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql);
}
```

I simplified the example. Here the `result`, what I got is **-1**. I copied the `sql` string value (after it's built) and executed in `SQLiteStuido` on the same database and it returned the correct value.

The `DatabaseFilePath` is correct. The connection is set correctly. I'm checking the same databases (in code and in `SQLiteStudio`). Any other idea?

Comment: I am pretty sure you need to use SqlQuery rather than ExecuteSqlCommand.

Comment: I tried it and it's working... thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call [SqlQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) method and not [ExecuteSqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.database.executesqlcommand?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) method. Since `SqlQuery` returns an IEnumerable you have to call Single. This is a the way to retreive scalar values from a query.

```
using (var db = new DbContext(AppIO.DatabaseFilePath)) {
    var key = 12;
    string sql = $"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeField={key}";
    var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(sql).Single();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(sql).First();
```